# File filter in Jacoco android test coverage report not working as expected

Tags: android, jacoco, android-jacoco

I am trying to add Jacoco to my project for test coverage reporting.

Referred the following blogs for that,

- https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/setup-jacoco-code-coverage-with-your-multimodule-android-app-kotlin-a0f82573a1
- https://azizbekian.medium.com/setup-jacoco-sonarqube-in-multimodule-multiflavor-kotlin-android-project-d8e7b27aed36
- https://medium.com/jamf-engineering/android-kotlin-code-coverage-with-jacoco-sonar-and-gradle-plugin-6-x-3933ed503a6e

Most of them have the same code for file filtering, but it is not working for me.

**jacoco.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

project.afterEvaluate { project ->
    setupAndroidReporting()
}

def setupAndroidReporting() {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        // Whether or not classes without source location should be instrumented
        jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
        jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
    }

    // Grab all build types and product flavors
    def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type ->
        type.name
    }
    def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor ->
        flavor.name
    }
    // When no product flavors defined, use empty
    if (!productFlavors) {
        productFlavors.add('')
    }
    productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
        buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->
            def sourceName, sourcePath
            if (!productFlavorName) {
                sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}"
            } else {
                sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
                sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"
            }
            def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"

            // Create coverage task of form 'testFlavorTypeCoverage' depending on 'testFlavorTypeUnitTest'
            task "${testTaskName}Coverage"(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
                group = "Reporting"
                description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."

                def fileFilter = [
                        // data binding
                        'android/databinding/**/*.class',
                        '**/android/databinding/*Binding.class',
                        '**/android/databinding/*',
                        '**/androidx/databinding/*',
                        '**/BR.*',

                        // android
                        '**/R.class',
                        '**/R$*.class',
                        '**/BuildConfig.*',
                        '**/Manifest*.*',
                        '**/*Test*.*',
                        'android/**/*.*',

                        // kotlin
                        '**/*MapperImpl*.*',
                        '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                        '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                        '**/BuildConfig.*',
                        '**/*Component*.*',
                        '**/*BR*.*',
                        '**/Manifest*.*',
                        '**/*$Lambda$*.*',
                        '**/*Companion*.*',
                        '**/*Module*.*',
                        '**/*Dagger*.*',
                        '**/*Hilt*.*',
                        '**/*MembersInjector*.*',
                        '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
                        '**/*_Factory*.*',
                        '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                        '**/*Extensions*.*',

                        // sealed and data classes
                        '**/*$Result.*',
                        '**/*$Result$*.*',

                        // adapters generated by moshi
                        '**/*JsonAdapter.*',

                        // Hilt
                        '**/*Module.kt',
                        '**/di/**',
                        'dagger.hilt.internal/*',
                        'hilt_aggregated_deps/*',
                ]

                def javaTree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/$sourceName/classes", exclude: fileFilter)
                def kotlinTree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/$sourceName", exclude: fileFilter)
                classDirectories.from = files([javaTree], [kotlinTree])
                executionData.from = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")
                def coverageSourceDirs = [
                        "src/main/java",
                        "src/$productFlavorName/java",
                        "src/$buildTypeName/java",
                ]

                sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))
                additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))

                reports {
                    csv.enabled false // change if needed
                    xml.enabled false // change if needed
                    html {
                        enabled true
                        destination file("${buildDir}/coverage-report")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Test coverage report: ${buildDir}/reports/coverage/androidTest/debug/index.html")
}

// Jacoco
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { details ->
            if ('org.jacoco' == details.requested.group) {
                details.useVersion "0.8.7"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The generated report still includes files from these hilt directories.

[image: Screenshot]

**Note:**
Also noticed it is not running/reporting any tests as the coverage is shown as 0%.

**P.S:** Please add a comment if any required info is missing in the question.

Comment: Hi @abhimanyu , Did you find any solution for this issue ? build directory includes autogenerated classes by Hilt. I think the coverage is shown 0% because of this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check `additionalClassDirs` content. If it is not empty, try clearing it with `classDirectories.setFrom(files())`. This should do the trick.

The coverage task does not have dependencies on `test` or `connectedTest`, so you have to run the tests manually before starting this task.